# Is there a better way to implement matlab's Logical Indexing using Eigen/C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, slice, eigen3

I've been looking all over for a more "eigen" way of implementing the functionality of Matlab's Logical indexing. Here's the best I could come up with. (Focusing on an int array here for simplicity)

```
//an attempt at matlab-style Logical Indexing
//equivalent to the matlab:
//  original = [1,2,3,4]
//  subset = original(original < 3)

using namespace Eigen;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

IOFormat OctaveFmt(StreamPrecision, 0, ", ", " ", "", "", "[", "]");

ArrayXi original(4);
original << 1,2,3,4;
cout<<"Original with bad values:"<<endl
    <<original.format(OctaveFmt)<<endl;

Array<bool, Dynamic,1> selections = original < 3;
cout<<"One if it's a good value:"<<endl
    <<selections.format(OctaveFmt)<<endl;

std::vector<int> picked;
for(int i = 0; i < selections.size(); i++ )
{
    if(selections(i))
    {
        picked.push_back(original(i));
    }
}

//put the vector values back into an eigen array
ArrayXi theGoodStuff = Map<ArrayXi, Unaligned>
                       (picked.data(), picked.size());

cout<<"Just the good stuff:"<<endl
    <<theGoodStuff.format(OctaveFmt)<<endl;
```

Here's the output I get:

```
Original with bad values:
[1  2  3  4]
One if it's a good value:
[1  1  0  0]
Just the good stuff:
[1  2]
```

Does anyone know how to do this in a more 'eigen' way, or just a faster way than looping through the arrays?

Comment: `std::endl` does more than just inserting a newline in the stream: it flushes the stream too, slowing down code significantly. You're better off using `'\n'` if you want only to insert a newline.

Comment: "*a faster way than looping through the arrays*" -- You mean faster to type I presume? Any such operation must loop through the arrays, even if it's a single function call. You could probably increase speed if you first count the number of elements indexed, allocate the output space for them, then copy over the values. `push_back` does require reallocation, it's O(n log n) for n elements copied.

Comment: Can you not take an element-wise product of the two arrays (selections and original). If you then get rid of all the zero elements (which were not previously zero), that should give you the same results.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the endl tip. I didn't realize that. What I mean by faster, isn't less typing. Eigen does a lot of fancy optimizations under the covers and here I am looping over a collection. I'm hoping there's some way that I can use some of them. I just used selections.sum() to initialize the size of "picked", then ran both versions a bunch of times with random numbers. It actually ran faster without initializing the size, maybe because the sum() takes O(n)? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Mansoor That's essentially what I'm doing, but without the added multiplication. The missing functionality in Eigen appears to be how to remove the unwanted elements. Thanks.

Comment: @hotplasma I don't think you are, you loop through the *selection* array and then selectively add to *picked*. I am suggesting an elementwise product of the *selection* and *original* arrays.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? If you actually want to extract all fitting elements, you won't be faster than a loop. If you want to do certain operations on/with all fitting elements, there may be faster ways.

Comment: @Mansoor If I do it your way, I multiply the selections by originals, then loop through to eliminate the zeroes. My way, I skip the multiplication and loop through all elements, only adding values to picked if the corresponding selections value is true. I've actually considered this. With your method, you need to be careful, because 0 is an array element that you might want to keep.

Comment: I tried to think of a way to do it using the indexes to perform the slice, but I couldn't think of a way to get the set of indexes any differently than the loop I'm already using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old one but....Eigen 3.4 makes it way cleaner to do this. Sadly I can't speak to the performance. I'm mainly interested readability. I made this:

```
class logical
{
private:
    const Index new_size;
    Array<Index, Dynamic, 1> old_inds;

public:
    logical(const Array<bool, Dynamic, 1> &keep) : new_size(keep.count()), old_inds(new_size)
    {
        for (Index i = 0, j = 0; i < keep.size(); i++)
            if (keep(i))
                old_inds(j++) = i;
    }
    Index size() const { return new_size; }
    Index operator[](Index new_ind) const { return old_inds(new_ind); }
};
```

Which is used like:

```
logical inds(ind_to_keep);
Y_slice = Y(inds); // vector
H_slice = H(inds, all); // remove some rows
R_slice = R(inds, inds); // remove the same rows as columns
```

Eigen help is at the bottom of this page:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html